# How to use Keychain access to store passwords in iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, keychain

Can someone tell me how we can store information in Keychain? How secure it would be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [Simple iPhone Keychain Code](http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code)
- [Apple: iPhone Keychain Backups](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-DontLinkElementID_3)
- [Is There Any Point To Using The Keychain API On iPhone?](http://jens.mooseyard.com/2009/06/is-there-any-point-to-using-the-keychain-api-on-iphone/)

> "What you’re left with is an encrypted flat-file database, specialized for just a few data types, with a really clunky and badly documented API. As I wrote above, its functionality could be duplicated, with a better API, without much effort. The encryption part is significant, though, since its primary purpose is to keep keys and passwords safe. A DIY key database could be protected by encrypting it with a symmetric key, and then putting that key in the Keychain."

Comment: HI Alex, Thanks. Update the third link to http://jens.mooseyard.com/2009/06/is-there-any-point-to-using-the-keychain-api-on-iphone/ The existing URL is broken.