# iOS app - advanced login screen

Tags: iphone, security, ios, authentication, keychain

I am building a login screen for a universal iOS application.

One of my requirements is a secure login screen that will store the credentials on device. 
All the tutorials I found on the web explained only on the UI part of the login screen.

Does anybody know any good tutorial from the security perspective of the login screen?

Cheers!
 m88m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to read about the iOS Keychain. I wrote a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143240/how-to-use-keychain-access-to-store-passwords-in-iphone-app/4143294#4143294) an hour ago in a separate Stack Overflow question about the Keychain, where your app can safely store and retrieve credentials put into authentication fields.