# Get data from a website to iPhone app

Tags: php, html, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a couple of questions. I hope people can give me a good view because I am stuck at the moment.

It's a year since I started developing so please bear with me.

1. How can I get data from a website that I don't own to my application? 
   I have done some database parsing before but that's all from my own website. I see people use different library's (HPPL for example). 

   But what if the website requires users to login? And besides does that work on HTML only? What about if it's a PHP based site?
2. Should I get the external data directly on the iPhone when opening the app or should I use a middle-man approach (server between external website and app that handles the info)?

3) What is the best way to save login information so that a user doesn't have to fill in every time he opens the app?

I am a bit confused about all the stuff so maybe you can clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

The question is extremely broad; so you will get pretty general answers.

Essentially, you are asking how to consume a web service.  For that question, I'd recommend one of several tutorials online, like [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service).  There are others.  That should give you a start.

You should understand the Cocoa URL loading system.  The documentation is very complete. You can certainly use third-party libraries for this, such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking); but I would recommend you understand the Apple -provided frameworks first.

> But what If the website has a login ?

Depends on what sort of authentication we're talking about.

> And besides does that work on HTML only ? What about if it's a php based site ?

No.  Should be no different.

> should I get the external data directly on the iPhone when opening the app or should I use a middle-man approach (server between external website and app that handles the info)

In general, a simple design should be favored over a more complex design so long as it meets your specifications.  There's probably nothing the intermediate server can do that the iPhone cannot - but we don't really know your specs.

> What is the best way to save login information so that a user don't have to fill in every time he opens the app I am a bit confused about all the stuff so maybe you can clear things up...

You will want to investigate the Keychain then.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143240/how-to-use-keychain-access-to-store-passwords-in-iphone-app) for a bunch of tutorial references.

Comment: Definitely.  So long as your server does!

Comment: How do you mean my server... If the website Is an aspx web service it should not be a problem right ?  Finished the tutorial you gave me. Excellent very easy to use. Now checking the documentation.

Comment: 'your server' in this case meaning 'the server to which you connect' irrespective of whether you control it or not.  aspx should work fine.

Comment: So I need to parse the data that comes back from the website. Or should i search on screen scraping because there is no json/XML api